# Why did user object is undefined in NextAuth session callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I use NextAuth for signIn with discord provider and I need to add userID into the session object. For that I use session callback but user object is undefined. When I try to add userID to the session object, I got an error like this :

> [next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR]
> https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Indeed, it seems the user object is undefined but I don't have any solution.

```
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    DiscordProvider({
      clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: { params: { scope: 'identify' } }
    })
  ],
  session: {
    jwt: true
  },
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET
  },
  callbacks: {
    async session({session, user}) {
      session.user.id = user.id
      return session
    },
    async jwt(token) {
      return token
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: It's most likely complaining about `session.user` being undefined hence throwing the error when you try to access its `id` property. What if you do `session.user = user` instead?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like that

````
    providers: [ 
        Github({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
            clientSecret:process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
        })
    ],
    database :process.env.DB_URL,
    session:{
        jwt:true
    },
    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise, {
        databaseName: 'AuthDb'
      }),
    jwt:{
        secret: 'secretCode',
    },
    callbacks:{
        async jwt({token,user}){
            if(user){
                token.id = user.id
            }
            return token
        },
        async session(session,token) {
            session.user.id =token.id
            return session 
        }
    },
}); ```
````

Comment: I came to this same conclusion, but why is the `user` thats passed into the `session()` callback  `undefined`? It feels like it defeats the purpose of even providing `user` if you have to append the user to the `token` in the `jwt()` callback. Not sure if it's a NextAuth bug or what, but everyone seems to have this same "solution". I appreciate your workaround, though! Just confused

Answer (score 2):

You can augment next-auth session types with `@types/next-auth` by adding an `auth.d.ts` file with the following:

```
import "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface User {
    id: string | number;
  }

  interface Session {
    user: User;
  }
}
```

More on this: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/671

Answer (score 0):

The user object in this case should be coming from a database, not from discord. The session user property from discord doesn't have an id associated with it. The id property would be from your own user model in a database that you connected and you would need to use an adapter to access it.

Answer (score 0):

lets say this is your code

```
callbacks: {
async jwt({ token, user }) {

  token.user = user

  return token
},
```

So the very first time both token and user will have data, lets assume token and user  will be in the structure

```
token = {
   id: "123",
   emeail: "123@gmail.com"
  }
 user = {
    name: "name"
    age: 34
   }
```

for some reason next-auth triggers this call back again and again but if you modify your code like

```
if(user) {
 token.user = user
  }
```

then if you console your token and user you can see, in those scenario where user is undefined token will have the user objet with it like

```
token = {
 id: "123",
 email: "123@gmail.com"
 user: {
  name: "name"
  age: 34
  }
 }
 user = undefined
```

so if you assigned the user to token with if condition whenever user comes undefined in next-auth,  token will have user object inside it and vice versa. So either it will be

```
    token = {
      id: "123",
      email: "123@gmail.com"
      user: {
       name: "name"
       age: 34
       }
     }


 user = undefined
```

or

```
 token = {
   id: "123",
   email: "123@gmail.com"
   }


 user = {
    name: "name"
    age: 34
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pran R.V's answer is the best. Among the official doc and all the GitHub discussions and Stack Overflow questions, he is the first one that explained why we have to use if statement in the jwt callback.
Literally no one else, including the official doc, has mentioned

> for some reason next-auth triggers this call back again and again but if you modify your code like

This is why user object is always undefined in jwt and session callback.

Answer (score 0):

When a user sign in next-auth try to call the JWT callback with the user object so here we need to use that user object and set it in token object like this:

```
async jwt({ token, user }) {
  if (user) {
    return { ...token, ...user };
  }
  return token;
}
async session({ session, token }) {
  session.user = token.user as any;// you can also declare type
  return session;
},
```

note that if you need to check if user is not undefined otherwise you're going to set the user as undefined.