# NextAuth user is undefined in session callback with custom session

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am using NextAuth and `CredentialsProvider` to login and want to extend the user/session to add a custom field. I overrode my `User` and `Session` interfaces. When logging in I am returning a user with the updated model in my `authorize()` func. My `user` object in the `jwt()` callback is valid when I log it, but then seems to immediately run again and `undefined` is logged. By the time the `session()` callback is called, the `user` object is `undefined` there (I assume because it somehow got set to `undefined` in the `jwt()` callback).

I came to the same conclusion as [this post](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/4117) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72073321/why-did-user-object-is-undefined-in-nextauth-session-callback), but it feels like this is incorrect. Why do we have to append the `user` to the `token` in the `jwt()` callback when the `user` is passed into the `session()` callback? I will attach my code/logs below to see if this helps debug.

**Models**

```
declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session extends DefaultSession {
    user: DefaultSession["user"] & {
      id: string;
      // ...other properties
      username?: string;
      // role: UserRole;
    };
  }

  interface User extends DefaultUser {
    username?: string;
    // ...other properties
    // role: UserRole;
  }
}
```

**Callbacks**

```
callbacks: {
    session({ session, token, user }) {
      console.log("User in session: ", user);
      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          id: token.sub,
          username: user.username,
        },
      };
    },
    jwt({ token, user }) {
      console.log("User in JWT: ", user);
      return { ...token, user };
    },
  },
```

**Logs**

```
User in JWT:  {
  id: 'clqd9un7t0004q9xh76tmqd4e',
  email: null,
  image: null,
  username: 'newuser'
}
User in JWT:  undefined
User in session:  undefined
```